# Login not working using Azure Active Directory for ASP.NET Core app

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-authentication

I have a web app that uses the Azure Active Directory (AD) login (Microsoft login), where I have a development environment, staging, and production environment.

The AD login works for my development environment, but I am getting an error when I try to use the same login for my staging environment.

The error I am getting is

> Your sign-in was successful but did not meet the criteria to access this resource. For example, you might be signing in from a browser, app, or location your admin restricts

I am attaching the screenshot for more details. Any help is highly appreciable.

Best Regards,

Janak Darji

[image]

I have tried to enter my public IP under the network tab as an allowed IP but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow steps below to find which policy cause the issue.**

1. Sign-in your azure portal, and click `Azure Active Directory`.

   [image]
2. Find the user, and click it.

   [image]
3. Find the sign-in logs.

   [image]
4. Then you can find the login record. And Click it to check the `Conditional Access`. You can find which policy block it.

   [image]
5. You can disable all the policy for test.

Comment: Thank you Jason for your help. I will try this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You are being blocked by a conditional access policy
[image]

In your Azure AD you can use the What If tool to troubleshoot Conditional Access policies

> The Conditional Access What If policy tool allows you to understand the impact of Conditional Access policies in your environment. Instead of test driving your policies by performing multiple sign-ins manually, this tool enables you to evaluate a simulated sign-in of a user. The simulation estimates the impact this sign-in has on your policies and generates a simulation report.

You can find the What If tool in the Azure portal under Azure Active Directory > Security > Conditional Access > What If.

[image]

Before you can run the What If tool, you must provide the conditions you want to evaluate.

The only condition you must make is selecting a user or workload identity. All other conditions are optional. For a definition of these conditions
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your response but in my case, the strange thing is there are no conditional access policies created yet.